# How do I get multiple values from query using OleDBConnection?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, email, oledbconnection

I have edited the previous code and tried this below, I have also changed the textbox into a listbox with the same name, but I now get no value in the listbox after running the below code:

```
myConnection.ConnectionString = providerEdit
Dim str As String
str = "SELECT [Email] FROM [PRD_Records] WHERE [ReceiveKMCWEMSAlerts] = Yes"

Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
  myConnection.Open()

  Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
  While reader.Read()
    txtCreateAnnTo.Text = reader(0).ToString
  End While
  reader.Close()
End Using
```

Comment: Probably a ListBox instead of a TextBox, and ExecuteScalar only returns one record, not many.  You should use parameters since that 'Yes' filter probably won't work.  Best to close that connection after you use it, preferably with a `Using | End Using` block

Comment: [`ExecuteScalar: returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored.`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). That probably will not compile

Comment: `txtCreateAnnTo.Items.Add(reader("Email").ToString)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your responses.... I found the problem with the code, it was very simple and I was just overlooking it. I update the coded below:              myConnection.ConnectionString = providerEdit
        Dim str As String
        str = "SELECT [Email] FROM [PRD_Records] WHERE [ReceiveKMCWEMSAlerts] = Yes"

```
    Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)


        myConnection.Open()

        Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
        While reader.Read()
            txtCreateAnnTo.Items.Add(reader(0).ToString)
        End While
        reader.Close()
    End Using
```